# Cannot access Kubernetes dashbaord from browser using Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am using Google Cloud and I am learning Docker and Kubernetes.
I managed to do everything but when I try to reach `Kubernetes-dashboard` I can't do it.

I get the following error when I hit the URL for accessing the dashboard ->

`User "system:anonymous" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace "kube-system".: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""`

Comment: In which namespace `kubernetes-dashboard` is running?

Comment: @aerokite 
Can you please tell me how can I find it, I mean as far as I know it's kube-system but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Need more information to find the problem. Kubernetes version, where are you running your kubernetes

Comment: `kubectl get rc -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml` update your post this this info

Comment: @aerokite there are all the details.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", 

GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538
b34a9ceb3e406689c"
, GitTreeState:"clean",
 BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", 
GoVersion:"go1.8.3", 
Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7+", GitVersion:"v1.7.12-gke.0", GitCommit:"f4f0bedb82a57dc
32b21b8f15fe01e0b8411356b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-05T03:35:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", C
ompiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: I tried to extract this by kubectl -version.
Was this okay or should I give some other information also?

Comment: @aerokite I tried running `kubectl get rc............` . 

The resulst I got is 

Error from server (NotFound): replicationcontrollers "kubernetes-dashboard" not found

Answer (score 1):

Seems like anonymous authentication is enabled in your Kubernetes apiserver. That's why when you are accessing Dashboard, its trying to access as anonymous user. You need to disable this.

Restart your apiserver with this flag

```
--anonymous-auth=false
```

Then you will be able to access Dashboard using basic-auth.

Comment: I really scratched my head a lot but was not able to do it .

Can you please come to that chat link?